# gboard disable multilingual typing

Tags: gboard

I have just bought a nokia 7 plus and I can't disable the multilingual typing. I tried going into settings for gboard under "text corrections" but the option to enable/disable multilingual typing isn't even there. How can I disable it? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings for Gboard → languages ↠ English (or the language you are having trouble with) and deselect "Multilingual typing" [image]