# How to enable multilingual typing in Google Keyboard (GBoard) app?

Tags: gboard, mi-a1

Until recently I had multilingual typing enabled on my keyboard. It was possible to swipe in German and English at the same keyboard without changing languages. The spacebar had "English - German" written on it.

Somehow it got accidentally turned off. Maybe by some gesture on the spacebar?

Now I can't figure out how to turn that feature on again.
The toggle used to turn it on in the keyboard settings is disabled and can't be turned on.

[image: IMG:]

The hint says that multiple languages have to be enabled. But where can that be done?

On the languages screen there are already two languages. Unfortunately they are also separate keyboards and I always have to switch with the globe button.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I had the same issue with German (Austria) but it worked with German (Germany)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an incompatibility or bug in newer versions of Gboard. The issue was solved for me by uninstalling all updates for Gboard.

Go to system preferences -> "apps and notifications" -> "all apps" -> "Gboard". Choose the 3 dot icon on top right and select "uninstall all updates".

This downgraded Gboard to version `7.5.12.211120321-release` where it works. It doesn't work for me in the current 
Gboard stable release (version `7.6.13.215505041-release`) nor in the current beta release (version `7.7.5.218156409-beta`).

[image: screenshot: uninstall all updates]

Answer (score 2):

Likely reason is that the second language you want is not installed in *language preferences*

- To do that go to System → Language and input →
  language  →
  preference  → add  language (the one you want to be displayed on keyboard).  If it is already there, remove and add ( You can tap and hold a language to change the order or remove language from the 3 dots menu on top right)
- Now check as in first screenshot (of your question ) to see if multi lingual option is shown ( it should be). Enable the option and tick the language.
- Long press or slide on space key to reveal option as shown and select the bilingual switch ( it is Telugu in first snapshot and TE in second ). Your keyboard should show as desired both languages. If it doesn't reboot and check

[image]
[image]

(Tap to enlarge)

**Edit** This didn't work for OP. Maybe the Gboard settings has *Show Language switch key* disabled (Language & input →Virtual keyboard →Gboard → Preferences →Show language switch key) . Enable that. Also see in this connection https://android.stackexchange.com/a/165509

**Edit2** OP found the setting to be enabled but problem continues so -  1. Update Gboard if available 2. If not, go to settings and from app info of Gboard clear cache and see if that helps; next, clear data of app ;also disable and enable app

Comment: Unfortunately even though both languages are enabled in language preferences the option for enabling multilingual typing stays disabled. Removed the language, rebooted, re-added rebooted again always still the same. Any more ideas? Don't want to do a factory reset.

Comment: Your answer provides a lot of good tips that could resolve similar issues and you tried very hard so I feel the bounty is justified.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this option by disabling Show emoji-switch key under Settings app > Languages & input > Virtual keyboard > GBoard > Preferences. Turn this off and the language icon will show up.

[image]

Comment: Turn this off - which key??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided here [gboard disable multilingual typing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202155/gboard-disable-multilingual-typing), do the following:

Go to Settings> Languages & input> Virtual keyboard> Gboard> Languages. Select a language for example English, then enable Multilingual typing. Also select the other language you want to appear on the keyboard (in my case French)

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I see @beeshyams has already posted the answer few minutes earlier than me

Comment: Unfortunately this option is grayed out and I can't enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried switching to "German (Germany)" from "German (Austria)" in "Settings > System > Languages & Input > Virtual keyboard > Gboard > Languages" and it worked! Gboard version 7.8.7.

[image: language settings screenshot]