# How to change the primary Gboard language

Tags: languages, gboard

I just set up a new phone and had to type something in Hebrew but hadn't yet actually set up the extra Hebrew keyboard. Instead, I ended up setting my Gboard default to Hebrew, and I cannot figure out how to change it to US again. I have added/readded the keyboards, don't even have Hebrew installed, but right now I still only see Hebrew as the supposed language of my keyboard. It's not.

How do I change this back without having to reset my phone and try again?

Edit: the issue isn't the languages I can add, as I can add any and all. The issue is that it always says Gboard Hebrew Israel even though I'm not using a Hebrew language at present (it shows regardless of whether there is a Hebrew keyboard added or not). It's simply that I want it to say US English again.

Edit2: I've uninstalled all Gboard updates repeatedly and reinstalled as well. No dice.

[image: I can't change the "Hebrew" to my system default]
[image: and nothing is actually using Hebrew. It's simply an issue of what it displays under Gboard.]

Comment: Have you tried "Add Keyboard" so that you get the Hebrew one back and then switch it back to "English (US)"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable multilingual typing in Google Keyboard (GBoard) app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203060/how-to-enable-multilingual-typing-in-google-keyboard-gboard-app)

Comment: I tried that question first. That's actually why I considered posting to StackExchange and not the Google forums. It doesn't address the issue. Why would it show Hebrew if there isn't a Hebrew language even being used? That's the issue. There's no need to add a language when the Gboard *display only* shows Hebrew. There is nothing straightforward about this issue for me.